# Method of approach for Equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let R be the binary relation on N×P(N) defined by (u, V )R(w, X) if and only if u×|V | $\leq$ w×|X|.
Is R reflexive? Is R symmetric? Is R antisymmetric? Is R transitive? Is R a partial order?

I understand from this question that R is a powerset of natural numbers multipled by another set of natural numbers. But what i dont understand is how can it possibly be any of these, like you cant have a nat number set where 1 is equivalent to 2 and 2 is equivalent to 3,

or am i misunderstanding the question as a whole? I need help understanding the questions mainly.

Comment: What does <= mean?

Comment: $R$ is defined on (i.e. is a subset of) the *cartesian product* of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathcal P (\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @copper.hat it means less than or equal to

Comment: Thus, $R$ relates pairs like $(u,V)$ made of a *natural number* $u$ ($u \in \mathbb N$) and a subset $V$ of $\mathbb N$, i.e. a set of natural numebrs.

Comment: What is the "formula" defining $R$ ? Two pairs $(u,V)$ and $(w,X)$ are relate iff the number $u \cdot |V|$ is less-or-equal the  number $w \cdot |X|$ where $|V|$ is the *cardinality* of the set $V$.

Comment: Now you can easily "visualize" $R$ using some simple examples : $V= \{ 1,2 \}$ and $X = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and e.g. $u=2$ and $w=1$.

Comment: In order to complete the exercise, check the defining properties of an *equivalence* relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set (call it) $A$ on which the relation has been defined is the cartesian product of two sets $\Bbb{N}$ and the power set of natural numbers $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$. 
$$A=\Bbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})=\{(n,A)\, | \, n \in \Bbb{N} \text{ and } A \in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\}.$$
So examples of objects inside the set $A$ are the pairs
 $$\left(7, \{1,3,5,7,11,13\}\right), \quad (1, \emptyset), \quad (23, \{2^k \, | \, k \geq 0\})$$ where the first component is a natural number and the second component is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$.

Two elements $(n,A)$ and $(m,B)$ are related if $n\cdot |A| \leq m \cdot |B|$, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of set $S$.

For example, $(1, \emptyset)$ is related to  $\left(7, \{1,3,5,7,11,13\}\right)$ because $0=1 \cdot 0 \leq 7 \cdot 6=42$.

Now we can explore the question in general.

**Is the relation reflexive?**

For that we need to determine if $(n,A)$ be related to itself for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and for all $A \in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$, i.e. can we guarantee that $$n \cdot |A| \leq n \cdot |A|\,?$$ 
Assuming that $0 \not\in \Bbb{N}$, this will be true for both finite and infinite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$. Hence reflexive.

**Is the relation symmetric?**

We ask if $(n, A)$ is related to $(m,B)$, should $(m,B)$ be related to $(n,A)$?

In the example I mentioned above, ask yourself, will $$\left(7, \{1,3,5,7,11,13\}\right) \text{ be related to } (1, \emptyset) \,?$$

Hopefully you can pick up from here.

Comment: I hope i am going the right way by saying, it is not symmetric because there is no way that the set A size is smaller than set B

Comment: But however i am a little confused as to how to discern whether its antisymmetric, because How do i tell that both are subsets of each other when there is only one power set given?

Comment: @AshwinSarith From the example I gave, if $\left(7, \{1,3,5,7,11,13\}\right) \text{ is related to } (1, \emptyset) $, then $7 \cdot 6 \leq 1 \cdot 0$, which is absurd. So the relation is NOT symmetric.

Comment: Wait anti-symmetry is not the same as not symmetric right?

Comment: @AshwinSarith for anti-symmetry suppose $a R b$ and $b R a$, then we should prove that $a=b$, otherwise it is not anti-symmetric. So Suppose $(n,A) \, R \, (m,B) $ and $(m,B) \, R \, (n,A)$. Then we have $n|A|=m|B|$. But this doesn't guarantee that $(n,A)=(m,B)$. For example, $(1,\emptyset)$ and $(2,\emptyset)$ are related to each other but they are not the same.